# Can Oxyplot Image Annotations retain the transparency/alpha of the Source Image

Tags: image, transparency, oxyplot

In Oxyplot, Image Annotations have a (double)Opacity property, ranging from 0 to 1. It is 1 by default. It appears that when an OxyImage is set as the Source of an Image Annotation the transparency/alpha of each pixel in the original image is ignores, and the aplha for the entire image is set off of the Image Annotations Opacity property.

Is there a work-around / solution for having Image Annotations retain the opacity of the original image?